# can't access my site from outside of the server

Tags: iis-7

I have an umbraco website on the server here, IIS 7. It is set to port 83 while the other existing site is on 80.

The other site is accessible from outside the server but the umbraco site is not. I assume that I need to allow traffic for this port or something but I have no idea where, how or what.

Comment: Did you make sure you added the port information on your URL?

Comment: yes, I go to http: //server:83

Comment: I take it that using just the server name takes you to the site on port 80?

Comment: it views me the IIS 7 screen. the other site, default website, has 3 - 4 sites under it. So if I go to server/site I get the site. But I could not put umbraco underneath it.

Comment: So umbraco is a defined website at the same level as the default website?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply

Comment: I fixed it by adding an inbound rule for port 83 in windows firewalls.